# 403 forbidden error, cannot find code responsible for request

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 error when accessing [elitehfp.com/proedu/calendar.php](http://www.elitehfp.com/proedu/calendar.php)
The page is requesting a resource (directory), and I can't find any reference to it in the code.

Chrome's console points to a line of code containing only a `<script>` tag

I can't find any code that is requesting the path indicated in the error in any CSS, PHP, or Javascript files that are included in the page.

Does anyone have any insight into the problem?  Why, if the resource is requested in the inline CSS, is the console directing me to a script tag rather than the offending line?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that you're trying to access that URL and are unable to, or that you are receiving the error when not trying to access it and are unsure why? Either way some more examples of the code would be useful!

Comment: The page is requesting the resource and getting a 403 response.  It doesn't seem to be affecting the overall functionality, but is adding about 200ms to the pageload time.  I wasn't sure why the resource was being requested, as I could not find any reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the image folder in your inline css.  That's why you're getting a 403 response.

```
<div class="categories contentInfoText 31toggleMe" style="background-image: url('images/');background-size:100% auto;background-origin:border-box;background-position:right bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

this is the error

```
url('images/')
```

You forgot to add the filename.

Comment: Holy cow. Thanks for the save.